# How to capture Click event or command in FlyoutItem

Tags: xamarin.forms

Having an issue where I want to capture click event or command in FlyoutItem in my AppShell. Currently I have the below Shell.

```
<Shell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:abc.Views.Courier"
        xmlns:out="clr-namespace:abc.Views"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:abc.Views.FlyOut" 
        x:Class="abc.CourierShell">
    <!--<Shell.Resources> 
    <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
        <local:HeaderContentView />
    </Shell.FlyoutHeader>

    <FlyoutItem Title="Home" >
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CourierMainPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem> 
    <FlyoutItem Title="Logout" >
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate out:LoginPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </FlyoutItem>
    
</Shell>
```

I want to capture the Logout where I want to put pop-up and also clear some logs when user click it.

So far I'm trying to research on how to do it, as I'm very new with mobile development.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Route in your `ShellContent`:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Logout">
        <Tab>
            <ShellContent Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate out:LoginPage}" />
        </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

And then override this in your AppShell.xaml.cs:

```
protected override async void OnNavigating(ShellNavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnNavigating(args);

    var PageUri = args.Target.Location.OriginalString;
    if (PageUri == "//LoginPage")
    {
        ShellNavigatingDeferral token = args.GetDeferral();
        bool answer
            = await DisplayAlert("Logout?", "Do you want to logout?", "Yes", "No");
        if (answer)
        {
            token.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

It should be "//LoginPage", or you can add a breakpoint on this line:`var PageUri = args.Target.Location.OriginalString;` to get the value of LoginPage.

Comment: Having an issue @jianwei-sun-msft I don't want to redirect to `{DataTemplate out:LoginPage}` until user click the Ok. I made like this

        `bool answer = await DisplayAlert("Logout?", "Do you want to logout?", "Yes", "No");`

Comment: @vcargo I updated the answer according to your need. It works well. Wish it can help you.